# what happens after changing the blocksize in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I know how to change the block size in hadoop. what happens after changing he block size,*how namenode changes the perivous datanode to current size*. If my cluster is very huge and i sumbit job on datanode on previous datanode, that is still doesn't undegone changes to current size .How this is managed by the namenode.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing really happens. In fact the Block size is a property of individual file. What you define in the configuration is a default value. You can specify a block size while placing or creating a file in HDFS. The property is stored along with metadata of the file as part of namenode metadata. if nothing is specified then the default value is used.

When the files are accessed, the block size property of the file is used and the file is processed accordingly. This is done based on the InputFormat chosen.

The bottom line is several files can exists in a single HDFS cluster with different block sizes. What you define in the configuration is a default value. If you change it, that will used for any new create operations where the block size is not specified. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: in such a case ,this is big problem considering that previous block size was 64MB and now configured to 128MB then for a file of 128MB to retrive the namenode will call only once consdering blocksize as 128MB where this file must be in two datanodes of 64MB(if nothing really happens) 
i don't think blocksize will be stored in namenode metadata.in such a case why storing the block size the developers might have given direclty to store size of data and namenode can acess it both do take equal space

Comment: @Nagendrakumar - Changing the default blocksize will have no effect on files already created - so the 128MB file with BS of 64MB will still have 2 blocks of 64MB, and will be processed by 2 map tasks. The Namenode does store the blocksize on a per file basis as Rags notes

Comment: @Nagendrakumar - as mentioned by Chris. It is the default. Each file will have it's own block size. The file processing as I mentioned in my answer, will be based on the file's block size not on the default mentioned in hdfs-site.